# How to perfom a melee Titan execution?

Tags: titanfall

When fighting Titan vs. Titan you can go into melee combat and try to punch the other titan. Sometimes (if the Titan is not auto-controlled) you can perform an execution, where your Titan will grab the enemy Pilot and throw him away. What are the requirements for this to happen? Does the other Titan have to be already doomed or are there some other factors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other titan has to be doomed, and you have to be in front of it. These appear to be the only requirements.

P.S. The differant chassis have different executions. Atlas - Throw. Stryder - Squeeze. Ogre - Beaten to death with the it's own arms.

Comment: The Ogre will rip off the opposing titans arms and beat it down with it's own arms.

Comment: you also need to be in front of the doomed titan, punching its back doesn't trigger the execution.